# Custom JQuery Scrollbar Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[image]

I am using a custom jquery plugin for scrollbars but its causing the content div to resize, shrinks the width. Check the screenshot I attached. Any comment will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: We need to see some code. We can't figure it out by looking at a picture.

Comment: The plugin I am using is JQuery Custom Content Scroller. http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Comment: Plus I am using Bootstrap 2.3.2 and those tabs in the pictures are made with bootstrap

Comment: Yes, I know that plugin, I used it once. But this is rather a question of your own CSS.

Comment: Without seeing the code it's impossible to tell, but it looks like the CSS/position for the scrollbar element is out of place and positioned inside your table (or whatever it is). Try `position:absolute` on the scrollbar container, and `position:relative` on your table, or move the scrollbar container out of the table.

Comment: check the application here. you can check the code by checking the source, its all javascript.
http://ascensionnexus.com/apanel2/

Comment: Anything so far?? I think the plugin alters the content div width in order to accommodate the OuterWidth of the scrollbar div itself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the plugin author.

The script needs to accomodate the actual scrollbar element, so by default, there needs to be a margin (otherwise the scrollbar would appear on top of your content).

The plugin adds the scrollbar **inside** the element which the scrollbar is applied (the div you use to call the mCustomScrollbar function). It's added inside it and not on its parent as the script cannot possibly know what your parent element is.

**The added margin exists in the CSS file** so you can change it, remove it etc. easily. 
Just edit jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css and you'll find it on the very top:

```
.mCSB_container{
    width:auto;
    margin-right:30px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Change/remove the margin-right property to whatever you want.

Additionally, the scrollbar element container (.mCSB_scrollTools) is positioned absolutely, so you can place it wherever you want:

```
.mCustomScrollBox>.mCSB_scrollTools{
    width:16px;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

To add the scrollbar on a parent element, just call mCustomScrollbar function on your parent div.

All scrollbar design is done via the CSS. In [plugin homepage](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/), under section "Styling the scrollbars" there's also a visual representation of all scrollbar markup for easy reference.

Answer (score 0):

Had to change the scrollbar plugin I was using, now I am using SlimScroll (https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll). This is the only scrollbar plugin out there that does not builds its div and force it in the container div automatically resizing the content size. SlimScroll is based on Facebook style scrollbar that becomes a part of the parent div. Thanks to all of those who asked for the code! :)